# Register OpenIddict entities into DbContext in another way

Tags: openiddict

Is there another way to  register the entity sets needed by `OpenIddict` onto a `DbContext` except calling 
`options.UseOpenIddict();` in `services.AddDbContext<OpenIdDictDbContext>(options => {...})`.

I have trouble with this approach, because I have more `DbContexts`, and I want to share `DbContextOptions`.

In .Net Core 2, if you can use non generic `DbContextOptions` for all `DbContexts` OR you must have nongeneric `DbContextOptions<T>` for all `DbContexts`. So, I would like the first approach if it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly register the OpenIddict entities from `OnModelCreating`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
        // Note: use the generic overload if you need
        // to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
        builder.UseOpenIddict();

        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

If you don't see the extension, make sure you have a `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` using and that your project references `OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore`.